# Combining year-month data to continuous month variable (lubridate)

Tags: rstudio

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vDDd.png)I've got the following dataset year-month variable going from 1995 to 1999 and months 1 to 12.

The months start at 1 again at each new year. I want to create a continous month variable from 1 to 60, i can't find the correce lubridate code for this, any suggestions?

Much appreciated,

Best regards, Joris

Comment: Can you add the input to question instead of an image link?

Comment: Problem solved already, thank you for the reply.